# Can i get documents from collecions i have on Firestore

Tags: android, google-cloud-firestore

I have my fire store set up and connected to my app. There are these categories and I want when I click on one category to fetch all subcategory from that category. Can someone explain to me step by step how to do that?

```
 public class BeautyIzbornik extends Activity {


    ImageButton imageButton;

    private FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
    private CollectionReference firemRef = db.collection("beauty");


    private FirmeAdapter adapter;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.firmeinfo);

        setUpRecyclerView();



    }

    private void setUpRecyclerView(){
        Query query= firemRef.orderBy("logo",Query.Direction.DESCENDING);

        FirestoreRecyclerOptions<Firme> options = new FirestoreRecyclerOptions.Builder<Firme>()
                .setQuery(query,Firme.class)
                .build();
        adapter= new FirmeAdapter(options);

        RecyclerView recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recycler_view2);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }



    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        adapter.startListening();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        adapter.stopListening();
    }



}
```

my Fire store  looks like this

This is my main category and subcategories:

[image]

This are subcollection from one subcategory:

[image]

And now in my Main activity, I open the main category and I want when I press on subcategory(whic are all displeyed in my main activity) I want to open new activity and fill it with items from that subcategory... I have more subcategories and items but I hope you understand what I want to show.
so i want to have my Main activity filled with categoriys,secnd activity to fill with subcategorys and third activity where i will display data of some items that is clicked in secnd activity i hope you understand me my englis is bad :D

Comment: Please add your database schema and indicate the exact items you want to get.

Comment: Post more information about your Firestore.

Comment: if you do not understand me i want to when i click on one card view to open new activity and fill ti with subcategory from that category i do not know ho to do that...

Comment: Please add a **screenshot** of your database and please also responde with @AlexMamo

Answer (score 0):

It would be more useful if you provided the database schema. But the idea is the same on all schemas.

```
 Query query= firemRef.document("myDocumentHERE");
  ...
```

You can get the collection of the "myDocumenthere" by doing the following

```
Query query= firemRef.document("myDocumentHERE").collection("myCollection");
```

I'd recommend reading the official documentation, there's code examples there and its explained much better.
[Source](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data)

Comment: lets make it this way....i have collection of cars....my subcollections are Audi Mercedes Bmw Skoda...and that is showin in my app....now what i wont is to when i click on Audi to open new activity and fill it with models like A6 A4 Q8...OK? and i want to know is it possible to write code that will check which collection is clicked and then open that subcollection...and then i want another activity where i can click on for example on A6 and get like details and pictures of that car....did i explain it ??

Comment: Yes. It's possible to do that.
`Query query= db.collection("Cars").document("Audi").collection("models").get()...`
In this query you will get all cars that are audi and all models.
Every document that is within the "models" collection, you will receive.

Comment: My question is can i write it in some way that my app will check in background which document is clicked and then open subcollection from that document....you see when i lets make it this way if i add another brand lets say Ferrari in data base then i need to update my app...i ask is it possible that app itself check which document is clicked and then open subcollection of that document, whatever document is clicked to open subcollection of that document

Comment: Yes it's possible. You can pass string variables documents. For example onClick in your recycler you can set a String variable which you get from the database. It could "Ferrari" or "Audi" or whatever.
You can use that variable on the query Something like `db.collection("Cars").document(model)...`
Where model is a string and it contains the car name

Comment: OK,now can you explain in to me...write like example code for me to look at....sorry for this but i really really need help with this project

Comment: Unfortunately it's impossible to write a query for this use-case because the data will be set at runtime as i said. Read the firestore documentation and if you have problems ask.

Comment: then can i check whic card(collection) was clicked with snapshot  then write querry to open subcollection from that collection? And if can can you wrtite example code pls

Answer (score 0):

> Can i get documents from collecions i have on Firestore

yes you can! do you want to display your data in recycler?

Try this. [Watch Now](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=76_O3ZDdpvo&list=PLGCjwl1RrtcR4ptHvrc_PQIxDBB5MGiJA&index=15)

[image]

to retrieve your `beauty` in document table, please use this:

```
firebaseFirestore...
String postId = doc.getDocument().getId(); //retrieving 'beauty` in document table
MyContent myContent = doc.getDocument().toObject(MyContent.class.withId(postId));
```

in Adapter class you will retrieve it again using this:

```
final String postId = contentList.get(position).PostId;
firebaseFirestore.collection("kategorije").document(postId).collection("beauty").addSnapshotListener(new EventListener<QuerySnapshot>() ...
```

please see his videos for details.